# How do I limit API access to known client applications in a Web API 2 application?

Tags: c#, .net, api, restful-authentication, asp.net-web-api2

I've created an application that is comprised of three main components:

1. A .NET Web Api 2 project that provides several WebApiControllers. Some methods, like "Register" are open to anonymous access, while others are authorized using token-based  Basic Authorization (the standard .Net Identity 2 approach included in the .Net WebApi2 templates). In the interest of quick-and-dirty functionality, this layer communicates directly with my database using Entity Framework.
2. An MVC5 project that provides a front-end web client and communicates with the Web API.
3. An iOS client that communicates with the Web API.

With this structure, end-users ("consumers") can create their own accounts using the unauthenticated "Register" API method. Users can then access and manipulate their own data via authenticated methods protected by token-based authorization headers.

Here's my question:

**How do I prevent unknown clients from making calls to the API, without creating significant overhead or overhauling the standard .Net Web API authorization functionality?**

Ideally, I'd like to be able to have some sort of table of identifiers for client applications so that I can allow new client applications or disallow them as necessary.

Comment: Restricting access is usually done in a Authorization filter, which would decorate your controller.
In the filter imlementation, you can check the token in you headers and possibly reject the request using :
actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);

Comment: I'm already using the Authorization filter for normal user-level authentication to specific API methods, but this doesn't give me a layer of protection to block unauthorized clients. In essence, right now any user can directly call the API to create an account and manipulate their own data. I'm particularly concerned about people calling the Register method (which has to allow anonymous users so that individuals can create an account) and spamming that method to create large numbers of fake accounts (I can distinguish these because I'm using email confirmation, but I don't want DDoS attacks).

Comment: In that case, you can store the attempts in a WebCache with sliding expiration (e.g. 1 minute) with the sesssion identifier as the key. Before every attempt, you will check how many attempts happened in the last minute and if its over a treshold, you stop executing the registration.

Comment: I have got the same question and looking for an answer??

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the knownClientApplications parameter in the Active Directory manifest.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-application-manifest